# How to use a custom couch.ini on Windows?

Tags: windows, couchdb, erlang-shell

I am trying to work with some third-party code that does

```
couchdb -a ./my/couch.ini
```

This does not work on Windows because the `couchdb.bat` file does not pass arguments through to CouchDB. So CouchDB always starts up on the default port (5984), instead of the one specified in `./my/couch.ini` (15984).

I tried manually passing arguments through by using the contents of the batch file. I.e.

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\CouchDB\bin"
erl -sasl errlog_type error -s couch -a /full/path/to/my/couch.ini
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything, i.e. it's still on 5984.

I tried a few variants of `/full/path/to/my/couch.ini`, e.g. `C:/full/path/to/my/couch.ini` and `C:\full\path\to\my\couch.ini` and `C:\\full\\path\\to\\my\\couch.ini`, but there was no difference.

Has anyone been able to run CouchDB on Windows with a custom `couch.ini` file?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a windows box right now to confirm, but you may not need to include the default and local parameters below. Add this just before `-s couch` in `couchdb.bat`:

```
 -couch_ini ../etc/couchdb/default.ini ../etc/couchdb/local.ini /path/to/custom/couch.ini
```

Notes:

- all paths are relative to `%COUCH%/bin/`
- the last ini file specified needs to be writable, this is where updated parameters should go
- secure your whitelisted parameters by putting them in one of the readable files first

FWIW, the unix syntax on my homebrewed mac version is:

```
usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R15B01/lib/erlang/erts-5.9.1/bin/beam.smp -Bd -K true -A 4 -- -root /usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R15B01/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home ~ -- -noshell -noinput -os_mon start_memsup false start_cpu_sup false disk_space_check_interval 1 disk_almost_full_threshold 1 -sasl errlog_type error -couch_ini /usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini /usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini -s couch
```

If you log a [jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB)  describing what you want to achieve, I'll see if I can get it into 1.3.0.

Comment: Why do the `default.ini` and `local.ini` configuration files need to be specified? Why not only specify the custom `couch.ini`?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should just edit your *local.ini* located under

`$PROGRAMS_DIR\Apache Software Foundation\CouchDB\etc`

CouchDB will parse this configuration file by default. I know it is not exactly what you've asked for but I guess that is the only way to do it.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't acceptable, as I have multiple applications using CouchDB, each of which needs their own configuration.

Comment: Got you. I'll update this answer when I find more information.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified in both:
*C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\CouchDB\etc\couchdb\local.ini
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\CouchDB\etc\couchdb\defaults.ini*

the section **[httpd]**
to be:

```
port = 5984
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

And restarted CouchDB. That helped